# Adding syntax highlighter to JamWiki-1.2

Tags: syntax-highlighting

The tutorial http://sinnerinc22.blogspot.de/2010/07/adding-syntax-highlighter-to-jamwiki.html describes how to enable syntax highlighting in [JAMWiki](http://jamwiki.org/wiki/en/JAMWiki).

My problem is that in the recent version of JAMWiki v1.2 the two files to be modified `WEB-INF/jsp/top.jsp` and `WEB-INF/jsp/close-document.jsp` do not exist any longer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third-party syntax highlighting tag extension available with JAMWiki 1.2 [link](http://jamwiki.org/wiki/en/Help%3aTag_extensions#a_.3Csource.3E) that may work for you

Comment: I am unable to get this to work using JAMWiki Version1.3.2.  There is a missing class file, org.jamwiki.parser.jflex.JAMWikiCustomTagLexer

Answer (score 1):

I have added [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/) to my installation just following SHJS instructions rather than JAMWiki instructions. Simply edit JAMWiki JSP pages to add content as documented [here](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html). To see how does it work, look into the source code of [this HTML document](http://ultrastudio.org/en/Special%3aReview?review=4ca60e46-0956-3f22-983c-e3ed986dfd03&pkg=1&cls=3&view=1).

You even do not need to compile anything after you edit JSP, the server does this for you automatically.

Comment: Do you think it'd be possible to list which JSPs you modified and post one as an example please? Thanks!  I'm assuming you can just edit the JSP straight from the .war and then redeploy?

Comment: Search for some text fragment you see in the generated HTML page (better directly from the HTML source code, not from a browser rendered content), over all JSP pages in JAMWiki project. You will find the matching JSP file very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I went ahead and posted an additional answer with complete details.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Audrius's answer, here's exactly what you need to modify.

1. `./jamwiki.war/WEB-INF/jsp/topic.jsp`  [Modify it to look like this](https://gist.github.com/garypaduana/11301202)
2. [Download the SHJS zip](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/doc/download.html) and copy all of the individual files from `./css/`, `./lang/`, `./sh_main.js`, and `./sh_style.css` from the zip to `JamWiki.war/shjs/`.  (This will flatten the directory structure so everything is now in `./shjs/`.  Flattening the structure is optional but it makes for easier paths when referencing them in the jsp.)
3. You can modify the `.war` with 7zip or dig into your web app container file system and place the JSP and shjs folder directly.
4. Redeploy or refresh as needed depending on your preferred edit method.